# How to show the exact output as per image on the cart page

Tags: magento2.2, cart, tax, subtotal

[image]

Products and Subtotal is showing with inclusive tax but tax amount is getting ZERO

How to show the exact output as per image on the cart magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below configuration setting

Set Configuration -> Setting Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Catalog Prices in "Including Tax"
Set Configuration -> Setting Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices In Catalog in "Including and Excluding Tax"

And Please set your shipping origin (Store->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Settings->Origin) to the same location as your store. Then make sure you have a valid rule and tax rate for your store's location. Then Magento will interpret the catalog tax rate as the same tax rate as the store's tax rate.